# Getting Json output, display in php USING REST PHP

Tags: php, python, django, json, rest

I have written Rest Api in python. and output comes in json format.

Like http://api.myserver.com/v0/movies

it will give me output in json format:

```
[
{"id":"1","movie_name":"Toy story","genre":["children","action"]},
{{"id":"2","movie_name":"Jab tak hai jaan","genre":["romance","Drama"]}}
]
```

Now I want output in readable format using PHP.

I heard that there is some concept of REST php. Which get output and store it in $rest variable and after that we can use it . So can somebody tell me how to do this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

`json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]]`

$json - is your json string

$assoc = When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

use `json_decode($json_string, true);` which will give you array